# MySQL Integer comparison speed (= vs <>)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, integer, comparison

I have a table with a field "active". Active is an indexed tinyint(4), but only contains a value of 1 or 0. I know... not great design, but I inherited this system to maintain.

If it helps, this table has 175277 records.

When I run:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE active = 1;
```

it takes 0.497 seconds.

but when I run

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE active <> 0;
```

(active has to equal 1 cause thats the only possible other value.)

It only takes 0.095 seconds.

I was doing some query optimization and noticed this and was wondering why?

Comment: How is the database knows that it either one or the other? So the two statements are not the same

Comment: `EXPLAIN` answered it. The engine decided to use a different key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

As suggested above, I used `EXPLAIN` to see what the query is doing and it turned out the engine decided to use a different key for each query.

Comment: When an index has low cardinality like this one, the optimizer can decide that an index lookup would be less efficient than just scanning the entire table.  Sometimes that's right, sometimes wrong.  Sometimes `ANALYZE TABLE` will cause the index statistics to shift, causing the identical query to use a different plan.